# Qlik get distinct count from multiple fields

Tags: count, aggregate, qlikview

I've been scouring the net for over an hour and cannot find what I need.

I have two columns that contain a persons name; `Contact` and `Created By`. Both are in identical format.

Basically I need to count the distinct values of BOTH these columns combined. e.g. The name can be in each column of data multiple times but I only want the name counted once.

I tried using the below but it is returning a number higher than the actual distinct values between both columns.

```
=Sum(Aggr(Count(Distinct [Created By]),[Contact]))
```

also tried this and am the same number is returned as the above.

```
=Count(Distinct [Contact] & [Created By])
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try something like this:

```
count(distinct Contact) + count({$<[Created By]-=p(Contact)>} distinct [Created By])
```

Basically, it adds the count of uniques from `Contact` to the count of uniques from `Created By` where `Created By` isn't one of the names in `Contact`.

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME!!! Thank you so much. I'm relatively new to Qlikview. Is it possible to add one more piece to it? Now that is working I've discovered I need to add where 'Created' is greater than or equal to 1/1/2016.Thoughts?

Comment: also what does the p in -=p stand for?

Comment: To save iterations this is exactly what I am looking to do now that I know that counting the distinct values between two columns is possible. I need to calculate the difference between the distinct count (contact+created by) at the 1st day of the year compared to current day/last day of the year, whichever is greater. e.g. 100 distinct at 1/1/2016, 125 distinct at 12/31/2016, value shown would equal 25. e.g. 150 at 1/1/2017, 166 at 3/8/2017, value shown would equal 16.

Comment: `p()` is a function that results in "the possible values" of the field passed. Its use in the above formula (without any set modifier) just results in all distinct values of `Contact`. The `p()` function has many wider uses. See [here](https://community.qlik.com/thread/113022) or try googling "Qlik P() and E()" for some more detailed info.

Comment: Assuming your data is set up so that if you were to select 1/1/16 in your calendar listbox that there would be associated names in `Contact` and `Created By`, you could modify the original formula like: `(count({$<date={'2016-12-31'}>}distinct Contact) + count({$<date={'2016-12-31'}, [Created By]-=p(Contact)>} distinct [Created By])) - (count({$<date={'2016-01-01'}>}distinct Contact) + count({$<date={'2016-01-01'}, [Created By]-=p(Contact)>} distinct [Created By]))`. If your data is set up so that 1/1/16 and 12/31/16 are cutoffs we'll have to modify this a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So there is a Created date column (Created) which each line item will have populated. There will also always be a Contact and Created By populated.  I have a multibox drop down where the user can select the year they want to view. If a previous year is selected the Created date should be from 1/1 to 12/31 of that year. If it is the current year it should be from 1/1 to the current date. Does that make sense?

Comment: Got it. I think I understand the setup. Try this: `(count({$<Created={"<=$(=max(Created))"}>}distinct Contact) + count({$<Created={"<=$(=max(Created))"}, [Created By]-=p(Contact)>} distinct [Created By])) - (count({$<Created={"$(=min(Created))"}>}distinct Contact) + count({$<Created={"$(=min(Created))"}, [Created By]-=p(Contact)>} distinct [Created By]))`. If a user selects a year in the interface, this will take the distinct name count for maximum `Created date` for that year and subtract the distinct name count for the minimum `Created date` of that year.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137594/discussion-between-bdiamante-and-user1590497).